# Assign a value to a column - xmltable

Tags: xml, oracle

I am extracting some data from a table which contains an xml file.
The query I'm using is the below and it works fine.

```
select RecUid.CD_UID,
   Abst2.*
from   testtable2 t
   cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default     'xxxxxxxxxxxx'),
                       'records/REC'
                       passing t.xml_file 
                       columns CD_UID varchar2(200) path 'UID',
                               --names xmltype path 'static_data/summary'
                               Abstract xmltype path 'static_data/keywords'
                       ) RecUid
   cross join xmltable(--xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
                       'keywords/keyword'
                       passing RecUid.Abstract
                       columns keyword varchar2(200) path '.'
                       ) Abst2;
```

I want to insert these fields into a table, but I also want to update a table field with a value which is not in the XML file.

I've tried with the below code:

```
INSERT INTO WOS_DM_KEYWORD
    (
      CD_UID
    , CD_KEYWORD
    , FLAG)
select RecUid.CD_UID
 , Abst2.*
from testtable2 t
cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
'records/REC'
passing t.xml_file 
columns     CD_UID varchar2(200) path 'UID',
          Abstract xmltype path 'static_data/fullrecord_metadata/keywords'
        ) RecUid


cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com    /schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
'keywords/keyword'
passing RecUid.Abstract

columns     CD_KEYWORD varchar2(200) path '.',
            FLAG '1'
        )  Abst2
;
```

But obviously it doesn't work.

We are running the: 'Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.4.0 64bit Production'

How can I assign a value to the FLAG field?

Thank you!

Comment: Why 'obviously' - you haven't told us what happens. Do you always want to assign the value 1 to the flag column?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it doesn' t work, as I get the error `Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:` And as it is a flag I would like to set this always at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORA-00902 error you get is because you haven't supplied the data type for the flag column; this works:

```
columns     CD_KEYWORD varchar2(200) path '.',
            FLAG varchar2(1) path '1'
```

or perhaps more likely:

```
columns     CD_KEYWORD varchar2(200) path '.',
            FLAG number path '1'
```

But as @Boneist shows, you can provide the fixed flag value in the select list, rather than trying to coerce it into the XML:

```
INSERT INTO WOS_DM_KEYWORD
    (
      CD_UID
    , CD_KEYWORD
    , FLAG)
select RecUid.CD_UID
 , Abst2.CD_KEYWORD
 , '1'
from testtable2 t
cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
'records/REC'
passing t.xml_file 
columns     CD_UID varchar2(200) path 'UID',
          Abstract xmltype path 'static_data/fullrecord_metadata/keywords'
        ) RecUid
cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com    /schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
'keywords/keyword'
passing RecUid.Abstract
columns     CD_KEYWORD varchar2(200) path '.'
        )  Abst2
;
```

But again use `1` rather than `'1'` if the flag field is numeric.

Comment: I think you can only assign numeric literals in the xmltable like that. At least, I couldn't work out a way to make the literal column return a string, eg. 'abc'. Would be interested if you know how that could be done.

Comment: @Boneist - with double-quotes: `some_col varchar2(3) path '"abc"'`. I'd still do it in the outer select list though...

Comment: aha! That's the one thing I didn't think to try, d'oh! Also, I agree; I'd do it in the outer select too!

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is assigning a literal value to a column, I would just plonk it in the select list rather than in the xmltable, eg:

```
INSERT INTO WOS_DM_KEYWORD (CD_UID,
                            CD_KEYWORD,
                            FLAG)
select RecUid.CD_UID,
       Abst2.cd_keyword,
       1 flag
from   testtable2 t
       cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
                           'records/REC'
                           passing t.xml_file 
                           columns CD_UID varchar2(200) path 'UID',
                                   Abstract xmltype path 'static_data/fullrecord_metadata/keywords'
                          ) RecUid
       cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com    /schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
                           'keywords/keyword'
                           passing RecUid.Abstract
                           columns CD_KEYWORD varchar2(200) path '.'
                           )  Abst2;
```